# Use iPhone as hotspot but connect with Bluetooth

Tags: tethering

The iPhone's "Personal Hotspot" settings provide options to connect using Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or USB.  I didn't want to use Wi-Fi to connect to the iPhone, so I tried Bluetooth.  The steps were:

(1) Pair iPhone with your computer

(2) On iPhone, tap Pair or enter the code displayed on your computer

(3) Connect to iPhone from your computer

On the iPhone, the laptop is then shown as Connected.  On the laptop, I turned off Wi-Fi to ensure that it isn't using public Wi-Fi. When I try to visit a webpage (say, google.com), it doesn't connect.

Am I misunderstanding the ability to connect to the iPhone using Bluetooth and then using the iPhone for its data plan?

Comment: What OS is running on the computer? Version number and vendor may help us help you. The iOS hotspot is agnostic and always on when tethering is enabled, so as long as Bluetooth is enabled on the phone and working you’re done setting up iOS side of things.

Comment: The OS is Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045.  The laptop is Asus TravelMate P2410-G2-M.

Comment: BTW, my question is more general than which party is malfunctioning.  I'm not even sure that I understand Bluetooth tethering correctly nor whether I have followed all applicable steps.  Should the laptop be able to connect to the iPhone over Bluetooth and use the iPhone's data plan?